# Module permissions class error

Tags: php

I have created a CheckModulePermission function in my user class which checks a module table to ensure the user has permissions to view the page. Below is the function

```
 public function CheckModulePermissions($moduleId) {

        if(isset($_SESSION['userId'])) {

            // If the user is admin, allow regardless

            if($this->IsAdmin()) {

                return true;

            }

            $sql = "SELECT `userModuleId`

                    FROM `userModules`

                    WHERE `userId` = " . $_SESSION['userId'] . "

                    AND `moduleId` = " . $moduleId . ";";

            mysql_select_db(DB_USER_DATABASE_NAME, $this->conn);

            $result = mysql_query($sql, $this->conn);

            $x = mysql_fetch_row($result);

            if($x[0] == 1) {

                return true;

            } else {

                return false;

            }

        } else {

            return false;

        }

    }

}
```

This works fine in all my pages except one page where it fails . I have a dropdown box and a text box which will be updated depending on the users permission. The user i am logged on as has the permission but the dropdown boxes do not appear.

```
if(isset($_GET['orderNumber'])) {

    // If post is set then update the prima reference and order status

    // Only if user has sufficient privileges

    if(isset($_POST['orderStatus'])) {

        if($user->CheckModulePermissions(11)) {

            $cid->UpdateOrderStatus($_GET['orderNumber'], $_POST['orderStatus']);

            $cid->UpdateOrderReference($_GET['orderNumber'], $_POST['PReference']);

        }

    }




if($user->CheckModulePermissions(11)) {

                            $content .= "<select name='orderStatus'>

                            <option value='1'";

                            if($orderDetails['status'] == 1) $content .= " selected='selected'";

                            $content .= ">Incomplete</option>

                            <option value='2'";

                            if($orderDetails['status'] == 2) $content .= " selected='selected'";

                            $content .= ">Submitted</option>

                            <option value='3'";

                            if($orderDetails['status'] == 3) $content .= " selected='selected'";

                            $content .= ">Processed</option>

                        </select>";

                    } else {

                        if($orderDetails['status'] == 1) $content .= "Incomplete";

                        if($orderDetails['status'] == 2) $content .= "Submitted";

                        if($orderDetails['status'] == 3) $content .= "Processed";

                    }

                    $content .= "</td>

                    </tr>

                    <tr>

                        <th>Prima Order Number</th>

                        <td>";

                        if($user->CheckModulePermissions(11)) {

                            $content .= "<input type='text' name='pReference' value='" . $orderDetails['PReference'] . "' /></td>

                            </tr>

                            <tr>

                                <td colspan='2'><input type='submit' /></td>

                            </tr>";

                        } else {

                            $content .= $orderDetails['PrimaReference'] . "</td></tr>";

                        }

                        $content .= "</table>

                </form>

            </td>
```

Is it the logic for the dropdown box where it fails?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more efficient/readable version of your `CheckModulePermissions()` method...

```
public function CheckModulePermissions ($moduleId) {

  // Deny immmediately if no userId is set
  if (!isset($_SESSION['userId'])) return FALSE;

  // If the user is admin, allow regardless
  if ($this->IsAdmin()) return TRUE;

  // Generate an SQL statement - does this need sanitising?
  $sql = "SELECT `userModuleId`
          FROM `userModules`
          WHERE `userId` = '{$_SESSION['userId']}'
          AND `moduleId` = '$moduleId'
          LIMIT 1";
  // Is this line really necessary? Are you actually working with more than one database?
  // Even if you are, it's probably better to do it in the query, like this:
  // SELECT whatever FROM DB_USER_DATABASE_NAME.tablename WHERE...
  mysql_select_db(DB_USER_DATABASE_NAME, $this->conn);
  // Since you only want one row, it's slightly more resource efficient
  // to abandon the $result variable
  $x = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query($sql, $this->conn));
  // This means the same thing as your if ... else
  return $x[0] == 1;

}
```

...and here is a rewritten version of the HTML generation code.

```
// Get this once, at the beginning, to minimise SQL traffic
$hasPermissions = $user->CheckModulePermissions(11);

// Uncomment this line to make sure that $user->CheckModulePermissions is returning the value you expect
//var_dump($hasPermissions);

if (isset($_GET['orderNumber'])) {
  // If post is set then update the prima reference and order status
  // Only if user has sufficient privileges
  if (isset($_POST['orderStatus']) && $hasPermissions) {
    $cid->UpdateOrderStatus($_GET['orderNumber'], $_POST['orderStatus']);
    $cid->UpdateOrderReference($_GET['orderNumber'], $_POST['PReference']);
  }

  // Map of status numbers to string descriptions
  $statusStrs = array(1 => 'Incomplete','Submitted','Processed');

  if ($hasPermissions) {
    // Generate a <select>
    $content .= "<select name='orderStatus'>";
    foreach ($statusStrs as $val => $str) {
      $content .= "\n<option value='$val'".(($orderDetails['status'] == $val) ? " selected='selected'" : '').">$str</option>";
    }
    $content .= "\n</select>";
  } else {
    // Print the current status string
    $content .= $statusStrs[$orderDetails['status']];
  }

  // Close the table cell (layout tables are nasty nasty)
  $content .= "</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Prima Order Number</th>
    <td>";

  if ($hasPermissions) {
    // add an input for changing the reference number
    $content .= "<input type='text' name='pReference' value='{$orderDetails['PReference']}' /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan='2'><input type='submit' /></td>
  </tr>";
  } else {
    // Display the current reference number
    $content .= $orderDetails['PrimaReference'] . "</td></tr>";
  }
  $content .= "</table>
  </form>
</td>
```

I think the most likely cause of your problem is that `CheckModulePermissions()` is returning `FALSE` when you expect it to return `TRUE`. Uncomment the `var_dump()` line to verify this and we'll take it from there.

Comment: thank you for that. Yes it is my function its returning false on anyone user apart from admin despite the fact that they have rights.. Im not too sure how to get around that really.

Comment: You need to find out *where* it is returning false - is it at the first check (i.e. `$_SESSION['userId']` is not set) or is it at the end (where `$x[0] == 1`). Change `if (!isset($_SESSION['userId'])) return FALSE;` to `if (!isset($_SESSION['userId'])) return -1;` and call `var_dump` as before - then you can see if you have a problem with the `$_SESSION` or a problem with your DB query. Could it be as simple as forgetting to call `session_start()`?